# Baking light increasing the batches in my scene

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine

I am new with light baking and trying to bake my scene in order to increase performance and graphics mainly targeting mobile devices.

The issue is that before baking my scene total batches were 100 , but after baking my scene batches increase to like  400 - 500. Also I would like to reduce the size which i have achieved somehow with playing with settings. Am I doing something wrong with settings?
[see my settings here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHkPS.png)

Comment: Please include your current settings, it is very hard to judge if you've got any settings wrong if we don't know them ;)

Comment: @remy_rm Thanks a lot for your quick response . I have attached an descriptive image . Secondly I haven't changed the object light map settings under Mesh render  component. My settings are set to very low resolution because less storage is also my concern.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would remove the static option of the terrain. This will increase your performance significantly.

Comment: I am not using terrain just simple models with plane ground.

Comment: is the plane tagged as static?

Comment: Yes It is static

Comment: remove the static option and bake the scene, if you still have performance issues, comment here

Comment: how can you bake without making it static ?